# form_for calls model method without submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an index page for admin part of my project

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p><%= review.header %></p>
  <p><%= review.body %></p>
  <%= form_for [:admin, review] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :approve %>
    <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_for [:admin, review] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :reject %>
    <%= f.submit "Reject" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

where `:approve` and `:reject` are public instance methods in `Review` model.
For some reason, when I load this index page, it automatically calls `review.reject` method which sets corresponding `is_rejected` field to `true`. Same behavior applies to `form_for` with `:approve` if I remove `form_for` with `:reject` bit.

`index` action from corresponding controller is very simple

```
def index
  @reviews = Review.all
end
```

I realize this must be normal behavior, but what I would expect is to call `reject` method only when I submit corresponding form. Is there a way to fix it? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Just for the future reference (including my own): it is easier to use `button_to` helper for things like that

```
<%= button_to "Approve", { :action => "update", :id => review.id, :review => { :approve => true } }, :method => :put %>
<%= button_to "Reject", { :action => "update", :id => review.id, :review => { :reject => true } }, :method => :put %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form builder is calling approve and reject on your model because it's trying to determine what to set the value for the hidden fields to. One way around this would be to not use `f.hidden_field` and just create a hidden field that's not tied to your model. You can use `hidden_field_tag` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That worked as expected with `hidden_field_tag "review[approve]"`